# Cascading errors involving "Expected incomplete structured construct"

Tags: f#, compiler-errors

Given the following code:

```
namespace Backend

open System
open System.Linq
open Npgsql

module helpers =
    let rec second_elms lst =
        match lst with
        | [] -> []
        | (d,o)::xs -> o::(second_elms xs)

    let folder acc elm =
        let result_list,acc_to_substract = acc
        result_list::(elm-acc_to_substract),elm

type ChartManager() =

    static member ConvertOutputNumbersToDifferenceSegments(listOfOutputValuesForADay: list<DateTime*int>) =

        let secs = helpers.second_elms listOfOutputValuesForADay

        let trans = List.fold
            helpers.folder
            ([],snd(secs.First()))
            secs.Tail

        let sndDateTime = fst(listOfOutputValuesForADay.ElementAt(1))

        for each_output in fst(trans) do
            yield (sndDateTime,each_output)
```

It's giving me lots of errors, but I guess the majority are just cascading errors from the main one in the "trans" block, which says (highlighting the word `helpers`):

> Unexpected identifier in binding. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.

What does this mean??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly indent with light syntax

```
 let trans = 
       List.fold
           helpers.folder
           ([],snd(secs.First()))
           secs.Tail
```

or

```
 let trans = List.fold
                helpers.folder
                ([],snd(secs.First()))
                secs.Tail
```

If it's a single statement, to split on multiple lines you need to indent passed the start of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
let trans =
```

the first thing after the equal sign `=` sets a new *offside column*. As long as you are writing only on or after the off-side column, you're defining the binding of `trans`. As soon as you write to the left of it, you're back outside `trans`, in this case defining the member `ConvertOutputNumbersToDifferenceSegments`.

However, when you go back outside, you often(*) have to go all the way back to some previous offside column. In this case the nearest one is set by the `l` in `let trans ...`.

Altogether:

```
(* v ----------------- offside column set by 'let' *)
(*             v------ offside column set by '='.  *)

   let trans = List.fold
       helpers.folder               (* <-- Half way back. Error. *)
       ...

   let trans = List.fold 
               helpers.folder       (* <-- Binding 'trans'. *)
               ...

   let trans = List.fold
                  helpers.folder    (* <-- Also binding 'trans'. *)
                  ...

   let trans = List.fold            (* <-- Binding 'trans'. *)
   helpers.folder                   (* <-- Binding in member `Convert...` 
   ...                                     Yields type error in your case. *)
```

There's a brief guide to offside columns [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233191.aspx).

(*) The exact rules vary by context.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, you are confusing the indentation as `helpers.folder` is not indented as far as `List.fold`

I would change it to

```
    let trans = List.fold helpers.folder ([],snd(secs.First())) secs.Tail
```